# Evaluate properties in Spring's context.xml (basic templating)

Tags: java, spring, templates, spring-el, property-injection

I'm wondering whether it is possible to evaluate properties in Spring's xml configuration files. I'm currently already injecting properties using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. But what I want to achieve is to inject a value, if a certain property is *true*, and inject another value, if it is *false*.

For example I want to set the hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in my persistence.context.xml to *validate* only, if my custom property `com.github.dpeger.jpa.validate` is *true*. I know I can specify defaults like this:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${com.github.dpeger.jpa.validate:none}" />
        ...
    </map>
</property>
```

But is there a possibility to somehow evaluate a properties' value maybe like this:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${com.github.dpeger.jpa.validate?validate:none}" />
        ...
    </map>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First option:*

You can use `#{}` EL expression and insert `${}` placeholder right into this expression:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" 
            value="#{${com.github.dpeger.jpa.validate}?'validate':'none'}" />
        ...
    </map>
</property>
```

---

*Second option:*

You can create separate property bean (note, that you have to define `xmlns:util` namespace and `spring-util.xsd` location):

```
<beans ...
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:appliction.properties"/>

    ...

</beans>
```

Now you can use this property bean in the EL expression by id:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" 
            value="#{props['com.github.dpeger.jpa.validate']?'validate':'none'}" />
        ...
    </map>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option was actually what I figured out myself given the existing answer. Although I don't like the notation using SpEL and property placeholder together, I'll stick to this option.